# How to solve Error "getLastRow" for Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I receive the following error when running my script: TypeError: Cannot call method "getLastRow" of null. (file Code.gs, line 15) but I am not able to find the issue. Here's the first part of the script:

function main() {

//Mail for alert

var recipient = 'MAIL Adress';

//Opens Spreadsheet

var SPREADSHEET_URL = "Google Spreadsheet URL";

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);

var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Budget");

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

//Gets the account IDs from column A to process later on

I've tried already with deleting all rows without content but that did not help either.

I really do not know what's the issue as I have used this script already. Maybe someone of you can help out?

Appreciate the help.

Thanks, Sabrina

Comment: Just means there is no sheet named "Budget" in your spreadsheet. See linked answers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - it worked and I am now frustrated that I have not figured it out myself :D